# how connect/configure repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, repeater

Is possible connect WELL wrc5010n to distribute wi-fi signal from another router?

Here is what I want to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

WDS should do what you want, but remember that WDS loses half its bandwidth per hop.  If you are just browsing the Internet that should not be an issue.  If you are doing hard core file transfers you might want to look into another solution.

One all wireless solution that would not cause you to lose half your bandwidth per hop is the creation of a wireless bridge between your APs.  To do this AND have wireless available to clients at both APs you will need to have at least 4 radios (2 at each end of the bridge), either by using 4 single radio routers or 2 dual radio routers.  I had a setup similar to what I am suggesting for about 6 years (first using 4 WRT-54G routers, then later using 2 DIR-825 routers) and it worked great.